# express post request won't get data

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, post, express

lately i started to play around with express.js the nodejs web framework. i'm making a simple form that send data to a express route.
I have a users.js route file and inside that there is a register route.

my user.js route file

```
router.post('/register', function(req, res, next) {

  var name = req.body.name;
  var email = req.body.email;
  var username = req.body.username;
  var password = req.body.password;
  var passwordConfirm = req.body.passwordConfirm;
console.log(name);
```

my jade file which form is in it

```
form(method='post',action='/users/register',enctype='multipart/form-data')
        .form-group
          label Name
          input.form-control(name='name',type='text',placeholder='Enter Name')
and go on ...
```

console.log retunrs undefiend.

my app.js . I used express generator to generate project, as you can see i have multer and bodyparser

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
 var expressValidator = require('express-validator');
 var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var session = require('express-session');
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var multer = require('multer');
var flash = require('connect-flash');
var mongo = require('mongodb');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var db = mongoose.connection;


var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// multer config inja
var upload = multer({ dest: './uploads' });




// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));


// // handle express session
app.use(session({

  secret: 'secret', //encryption key
  saveUninitialized:true,
  resave:true

}));

// // Passport
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());


app.use(expressValidator({
  errorFormatter: function(param, msg, value) {
      var namespace = param.split('.')
      , root    = namespace.shift()
      , formParam = root;

    while(namespace.length) {
      formParam += '[' + namespace.shift() + ']';
    }
    return {
      param : formParam,
      msg   : msg,
      value : value
    };
  }
}));

app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));


  // flash messaging via connect-flash
  app.use(flash());


  app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.locals.messages = require('express-messages')(req, res);
  next();
});


app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    });
  });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  });
});


module.exports = app;
```

Comment: Do you have 'body-parser' middleware included?

Comment: Dont use your app to test route functionality. there are too many things that can go wrong. use [postman](https://www.getpostman.com/). This way you can test the route and not the full data flow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to configure an express middleware to parse the body of your HTTP request before hitting your `/register` route.

#### `multipart/form-data` enctype

This kind of type is often use for file upload. A library like [Multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer) can be helpful for this use case.

I don't see a file to upload in your example. So you should consider using a simple enctype like application/x-www-form-urlencoded enctype (default) (see below).

If you still want to use form-data enctype without file upload, you can use a library like [express-busboy](https://github.com/yahoo/express-busboy) (built on top of [busboy](https://github.com/mscdex/busboy)).

```
var app = express();
var bb = require('express-busboy');
bb.extend(app);

// ...
router.post('/register', function(req, res, next) {
// req.body contains your fields.
// ...
```

#### `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` enctype (default)

If you configure your form to use the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` enctype, it's a little bit easier to handle in your route.

`body-parser` can be use as a middleware too: https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser#bodyparserurlencodedoptions

```
var app = express();
// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded());
// ...
router.post('/register', function(req, res, next) {
// ...
```

```

Comment: You're welcome. If your problem is fixed, accept the answer :)

Comment: I had updated the post, i have multer and bodyparser in my app.js, but it's not working yet

Comment: @moeinrahimi I updated my answer. Let me know if it's better for you :)